# Converting a List<double> to a DataTable is taking a lot of time

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I'm building a small software for my clients where they need to read data from 3 `list<double>`. Each list contains around 50000 data points, they supply the lists to me as an array :

```
List<double>[] MyVars = new List<double>[3];
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    string tempRowCell = "";
    tempRowCell = grdMaapingView.GetRowCellValue(0,
        grdMaapingView.VisibleColumns[x].FieldName).ToString();
    grdMaapingView.GetRowCellValue(x,
        grdMaapingView.VisibleColumns[x].Name.ToString());
    MyModifiedTable.Columns.Add(tempRowCell, typeof(string));
    MyVars[x] = Pressin.GetValuesByFilter(tempRowCell).Values.ToList(); 
}

for (int c = 0; c < MyModifiedTable.Columns.Count; c++)
{
    foreach (double v in MyVars[c])
    {
        string temp = MyModifiedTable.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString();
        DataRow TempRow = MyModifiedTable.NewRow();
        TempRow[temp] = v;
        MyModifiedTable.Rows.Add(TempRow);
    }
}

grdResults.DataSource = MyModifiedTable.DefaultView;
```

The problem is I'm reading of the data successfully but it takes a long 75 seconds to read it. What is the problem with the code I have written?

Please if you have any suggestion it's very welcome.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. I suggest that you benchmark your code precisely (use the `Stopwatch` class) to find out *which part* of your code is taking up most of the time.

Comment: Sir , i already used the Stopwatch Class , and the time is how i did get the 75 seconds , don't you think it is a bit too much for this amount of data

Comment: @user4281377: Which part of the code is slow?

Comment: MyVars[x] = Pressin.GetValuesByFilter(tempRowCell).Values.ToList();

Comment: Then you should benchmark GetValuesByFilter.

Comment: It turned out that the key / value  that being readed was not mapped correctly , so it was taking alot of time , on the other side the code was ok